# Readymade delegates in ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: c#, delegates

What are the readymade delegates like

```
delegate void Action<T>(T obj);
delegate TOutput Converter<TInput, TOutput>(TInput input);
delegate Boolean Predicate<T>(T obj);
Function delegate
```

available in ASP.NET 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to print a list, although the list will also contain any special-purpose delegates too:

```
foreach (Type t in typeof(object).Assembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (t.IsPublic && typeof(Delegate).IsAssignableFrom(t))
        Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of these are 3.5 c# stuff so the answer is no one
(but you can declare them by your own)

Comment: Not true! All of the delegates mentioned in the question are available in version 2 of the framework.